# List to string Conversion Cause Double u and black Slashes in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a list in python and my main Goal was to 
**Convert that list to string using**

```
fields =[(u'ABC', u'XYZ', u'AAA', u'BBB, u'CCC', u'DDD')]

fields Data type : <type 'list'>: 

my_fields = ','.join(str(e) for e in list(fields))
```

But I don't Know why  **my_fields** contains result such like this

```
'(u\\'ABC\\', u\\'XYZ\\', u\\'AAA\\', u\\'BBB\\', u\\'CCC\\', u\\'DDDD\\')'
```

But **i was expecting Result like this**

```
'ABC ,XYZ,AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD'
```

So i try to remove  ( u\\ ) **u and  Back slashes** using

```
 my_fields = my_fields.replace("u\\", "")
```

But it not work at all

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does `fields` contain? Edit your question to add that _important detail_ that you seemed to think wasn't important enough to mention.

Comment: So you are converting a string to a list, and use a list comprehension to convert that list to a string ?
Why?
Please show `fields`

Comment: fields =
<type 'list'>: [(u'ABC', u'XYZ', u'AAA', u'BBB, u'CCC', u'DDD')]

Comment: You have a list, with a single item in it, a `tuple`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try flattening `fields` before calling `join`.

```
my_fields = ','.join([x for f in fields for x in f])
```

Comment: how about : `my_fields = ','.join(list(fields[0]))`

Comment: @Loïc That would be one's first thought, but obviously would fail if `my_fields` had more than one tuple. That's why I decided to flatten it in the first place.

Comment: Finally, that there are much better ways to flatten a list of tuples in python than list comprehensions, like `list(sum(fields, ()))`

Comment: @Loïc  Also, `sum` on data structures is _VERY SLOW_, because you create a new structure each time you sum them, there's nothing better about that over this.

Comment: Stop begging for upvotes on your answers. Moderators have already deleted several such comments here. You should know better.

Comment: @CodyGray for future reference, what would _you_ do if you were downvoted by someone who obviously doesn’t know what they’re talking about? The downvote on this post was inspired by personal vendetta (take my word for it).

Comment: I would do nothing. Secure in the knowledge that my answer was correct and helpful, a single downvote is quite irrelevant and can be totally ignored. I've gotten several inexplicable or uninformed downvotes over the years. More than made up for by the inexplicable or uninformed upvotes. :-) Seriously, begging for votes is just unbecoming, and not part of the example we want to set for other users. Even if I could trust that *you'd* only do it in extreme circumstances, most people don't have that good of judgment, and would do it all the time. (In fact, many do. Lots of work to clean up.)